# How to get current logged in user role jwt nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jwt, express-jwt

Hello i'm using MEAN stack and jwt to login,
I want to restrict some of the data for only userRole 'admin'
This is my **user.js**

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {type : String, required : true , unique : true},
    password: String,
    role: {type : String, enum: ["reader", "admin"]},
});
```

This is how i verify the jwt token

```
function verifyToken(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.headers.authorization) {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request')
  }
  let token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1]
  
  if(token === 'null') {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request')    
  }
  let payload = jwt.verify(token, 'secretKey')
  if(!payload) {
    return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized request')    
  }
  
  
  req.userId = payload.subject
  next()
}
```

and this is the data i want to restrict for only 'admin' role using that verifyToken function

```
router.get('/special', verifyToken, (req,res) => {
    let specialEvents = [//data...]
}
```

My question is how do i access the current logged in user info and only make /special only readable by an admin

Comment: don't you get the payload inside the "req" object? Can't you check the enum value inside /special and return if it's not "admin"?

Comment: console.log(req). Please paste what this prints.

Comment: I got it working finally thank you

Answer (score 2):

Hi you need add couple of thing in you code. (As you need to put more detail).

```
// Generate an access token
const accessToken = jwt.sign({ username: user.username,  role: user.role }, accessTokenSecret);

const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];
    jwt.verify(token, accessTokenSecret, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.sendStatus(403);
        }
        res.locals.loggedUser = user;
        return next();
    });
```